# Debug Assertion Failed?

Tags: c, assertion

I'm fairly new to coding (currently learning C) and I'm confused as to why this error occurs when I'm running the console.

[The Error that I get.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQ5XA.png)

Here's the code that I wrote (it's a function that I call in the main to run a simple calculator program), I'm still not completely done my switch, but I'm pretty sure it should work with just that! (I think).

```
void part2() {

    printf("Welcome to Part 2!\n\n\nThis is a basic calculator!\nPlease select one of the following options:\n\n");
    printf("1) - Addition\n");
    printf("2) - Subtraction\n");
    printf("3) - Multiplication\n");
    printf("4) - Division\n");
    printf("0) - Exit Program\n\n");


    int selectionNum = 0;

    float operand1 = 0;
    float operand2 = 0;
    float result = 0;

    scanf_s("%d",selectionNum);

    switch (selectionNum) {

        case '1' :

            printf("_ + _ = _\n");
            printf("Please enter the first addend: ");
            scanf_s("%f", operand1);
            printf("\n\n");

            printf("%f", operand1);
            printf(" + _ = _\n");
            printf("Please enter the second addend: ");
            scanf_s("%f", operand2);
            printf("\n\n");

            result = operand1 + operand2;

            printf("%f", operand1);
            printf(" + ");
            printf("%f", operand2);
            printf(" = ");
            printf("%f", result);

            break;

        default :

            printf("\n\nYou entered an invalid option! :(\n Try again!");

    }

    printf("done.");

}
```

Does anyone know what might be the issue? :(

Comment: `scanf_s("%d",selectionNum);` you sure the `&` is not required?

Comment: Turn up your warnings, then start passing your `scanf` arguments by address.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Ahhh yes that's my mistake, thanks so much! It works now haha :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting [the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before posting._

Answer (score 2):

The problem is how you call scanf_s function. You should pass the pointers to the variables, where you want to get the results, not just the variables themselves. So write

```
scanf_s("%d",&selectionNum);
```

instead of

```
scanf_s("%d",selectionNum);
```

The same is true for all of the scanf_s call in your code.

Comment: Ahhh thanks so much, that was the mistake! :)